# How to prevent an AWS lambda function from running more than once simultaneously?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got a lambda function and I would like to make sure that it's never being called a second time if it's already running. Is there any option to force this behavior?

Comment: A file lock on s3 :)

Comment: @RickyA you might want to look into S3's consistency model before recommending that.

Comment: A lock in zookeeper/etcd/consul?

Comment: @MarkB hence the smile, but yes not a real solution

Comment: @RickyA DynamoDB is the generally recommended way for implementing locks across distributed systems in AWS.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know about the guaranties of dynamoDB. How fast does it update a key and propagate the change to the replica's. Locking in zk is specificly made for this usecase in that it is is virtually impossible to acuire a lock if a key is already locked.

Comment: Well if you don't know about it you could fix that by reading the documentation instead of speculating: https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/ "A strongly consistent read returns a result that reflects all writes that received a successful response prior to the read."

Comment: This is hack I haven't yet tried: The Lambda VPC might offer additional help of limiting concurrent runs. According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html amount of IPs in a subnet limits concurrency. According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html smallest block size is /28 which should give you 14 ip addresses. If you somehow consume 13 of those ip addresses, only one is left for Lambda. This might help together with other suggested solutions assuming your application is ok with failing events (you don't need to process all of those).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I limit concurrent invocations of an AWS Lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028897/can-i-limit-concurrent-invocations-of-an-aws-lambda)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Lambda currently doesn't support this behavior. You could try using DynamoDB to create a lock, but that's obviously not the most ideal scenario. Right now this use case isn't a very good fit for Lambda.

I have a job that I need to ensure only one is ever running, and I wasn't happy with any Lambda solution for that. I ended up just running it on a t2.nano instance.

Answer (score 5):

2021: Lambda now support concurrency setting. Change the reserve concurrency setting to 1 for this

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/?nc1=f_ls) says that the service is designed to run functions in parallel.

[image: FAQ]

However, you could manage this from your application if you are using the **microservice-http-endpoint** blueprint. You can do it since this kind of blueprint is just a web service that you can call somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a workaround by copying file to transient bucket and put an if condition
In case any other Lambda triggers
It will come out due to if condition