# Not able to change lamba function concurrency limit in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, concurrency

**I wanted to change the lambda function's concurrency limit but I was encountering the following problem.**

[image: AWS gui screen shot]

[image]

Comment: Well, have you tried doing what the error message suggests?

Comment: Even if I set limit above 10 it shows same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028897/can-i-limit-concurrent-invocations-of-an-aws-lambda